# Как в окне JDialog добавить кнопки свернуть и развернуть?

Tags: java, swing

По умолчанию отображает окно только с кнопкой закрыть.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Напрямую - никак, потому что это несколько нарушает идеологию. Диалоговые окна придуманы для запроса у пользователя каких-либо входных данных для работы приложения и вывода сообщений, поэтому они не предусматривают распахивания на весь экран и сворачивания.

Воспользуйтесь простым JFrame. Если вам нужна модальность - ее можно достичь при помощи [некоторых ухищрений](http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/are_you_missing_maximize_button).

Comment: пища для ума автору вопроса и подтверждение вышесказанного:

    public class javax.swing.JDialog extends java.awt.Dialog 
    public class java.awt.Dialog extends java.awt.Window

    public class javax.swing.JFrame extends java.awt.Frame
    public class java.awt.Frame extends java.awt.Window